# Will formula fields update on api / bulk api update?

Tags: formula, field-update, update, bulk-api

We're trying to figure out whether we should expect formula fields to behave as if the object in which those fields exist has been manually user-modified when we're updating records in that object, and whether there's a different result based on the api used. If it helps, we're using DemandTools as our utility for the planned record update.

Comment: Formula fields behave the same regardless of the way the record was updated/created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formula fields are executed at runtime - they only update when the field is viewed in a page or report, or referenced by another formula. The values aren't stored in the database. So whether the record is updated by hand or by an API makes no difference.

(A possible exception will be if you're indexing formula fields for the purpose of faster SOQL queries - I don't know how the indexed fields are updated. But this isn't common.)